# UISlider and playing sound in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, uislider

I'm trying to use a `UISlider` to play sound in a fashion which emulates how a violin bow would play on a string. At current, I can get sound playing from the slider however the functionality isn't correct.

```
    -(IBAction) slider 
{
           NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"im_on" ofType:@"mp3" ];
           if (song) [song release];
           song = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
           [song play];       
}
```

This is code and there is not much else to it. I have linked this method in IB to a slider which is triggered on the event `Value Changed`. When set to `continuous = YES`, when the slider begins to slide, the sound plays. However if it continues to slide the sound will stop until the slider stops where it then play again. When set to `continuous = NO`, the sound does not play when the value changes but when the touch is lifted. the sound continues to play while the value is hanging after that.

Is there a way to have the sound continue to play until the slider stops/changes direction/touch is released? i.e override all but the first `value changed` sent event until x condition is met.

Comment: TL;DR. You can't play sounds in Xcode, because Xcode is not a media player. What do you want?

Comment: The last two bullet points are the main questions, im using AVAudioplayer.

Comment: @Ray On Stackoverflow we generally like to see code in questions - since you've clearly got some, how about posting some pertinent parts of it (but not all...).

Comment: I've posted code and overhauled the question.